# how to change a specific records in Mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb

I have a database in MongoDb and it contains a collection called users that has information about people like name,job title,gender,etc.the problem is genders are wrong in most cases I mean the name is a male name but the gender is female although it had to be male.
I would be happy if you could help me find a way to write a python code to fix the problem.
I have two files containing names of females and names of males and here is the code I have written but it is not working since some of the records remain un changed and I do not know what is wrong:

"""

```
import json
import sys
from pymongo import MongoClient
from tqdm import tqdm

client = MongoClient("mongodb://192.168.20.92:27017")
users = client["97_Production_DB"]["invalid"]
updated_users_sepid = client["db_97_updated"]["users"]
invalid_users_sepid = client["db_97_updated"]["invalid"]

with open("male.json", "rb") as f:
    male = json.load(f)

with open("female.json", "rb") as f:
    female = json.load(f)

person = {}

for key in male:
    person[key] = True

for key in female:
    person[key] = False

for data in tqdm(users.find(no_cursor_timeout=True)):
    firstName = data["firstName"].replace("سید", "").replace("سیده", "").replace("سادات", "").replace(" ", "")
    if firstName in person.keys:
        data["gender"] = person.get(firstName)
        updated_users_sepid.insert_one(data)
    else:
        invalid_
```

"""

Comment: Are there any clues as to which names are not updated; an obvious issue might be that the name isn't in one of the files, or doesn't exactly match.

Comment: @BellyBuster yeah , you are right but the issue is in our database we want to correct the gender records that are wrong or null and for this goal we need to compare name we JSON files another issue which is my main question is that names are in Persian and they have prefixes with different ASCI codes which I do know how to delete them before comparing names with the file